# How to automatically replace url in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Below is an extract from a `.htaccess` file that redirects all `www` to `non-www` with https and it works fine.

My challenge is that I want to use this as a skel directory `.htaccess` file for all new accounts on my server. Therefore I need a way to replace yourdomain.co.nz with the url for each account that will be created.

I have used `%{HTTP_HOST}%` to replace all the url but then it does not redirect to `non-www`.

Help please!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.co.nz$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://yourdomain.co.nz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```